# Spring security @PreAuthorize hasRole() properties injection

Tags: java, spring-security

Assuming that my Spring Security and properties are configured properly, I would like to use role name from property like

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('${role.rolename}')")
public void method() {}
```

I have tried like in above code sample but it does not work (it takes '${role.rolename}' String as role to compare)

If I switch to

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public void method() {}
```

it works just fine. 
My motivation to such usage is better flexibility in application tests on various environments.

Comment: We have some `@Configuration` where `@Bean PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is configured, but I'm pretty sure that property is wired properly because when I define in the same class where secured method:  

`@Value("${role.rolename}")
private String ROLE_NAME;`

Correct value is present

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to remove `''` signs:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(${role.rolename})")
public void method() {}
```

**EDIT.** I am sure that there is a better way, but as a workaround you can call some method on some bean:

```
@Component("appVariablesHolder")
public class AppVariablesHolder {

    @Value("${role.rolename}") 
    private String someRole;

    public String getSomeRole() {
        return this.someRole;
    }
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole(@appVariablesHolder.getSomeRole())")
public void method() {}
```

Comment: When I removed `''` signs, I got:

`Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 9): Unexpected token.  Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'`

property name replacement changed nothig

Comment: Try to replace `$` by `#` : @PreAuthorize("hasRole(#{role.rolename})")

Comment: it's clear from this answer that the single quotes are wrong, but it would seem that we should be able to reference the properties with ${}, but it doesn't seem to work :( -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836387/can-spring-evaluate-all-characters-expressions-in-spel-expressions-as-they-are-i

Answer (score 2):

I've found that you can just grab the propertyResolver and pull values directly from that, instead of writing your own class as was suggested by @Maksym.

Exammple:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(@environment.getProperty('role.rolename')")
public void method() {}
```

Comment: `
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'propertyResolver' available`

Comment: @jbx - You need to use the bean name of whatever your property resolver is. So if you’ve named yours something else, swap that in instead.

Comment: And how is that different from writing your own class?

Comment: Spring provides a property resolver, without having to write one. You just need to make sure you use the bean name that spring assigns to it (whatever that is, or if you've renamed the bean). This works for me. I use it on all of my controllers that need security.

Comment: So maybe you need the configuration part which initialises the property resolver as a `@Bean`, and you have it somewhere else in your code? On its own this line doesn't work.

Comment: @jbx - You are right. I had mine overridden. Try @environment.getProperty(...) instead. That is the default name that Spring Boot assigns the property resolver. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building on other answers here, one thing that tripped me up was not setting the context on the `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`.

Make sure that in your `MethodSecurityConfig` you're loading the context for the answers above to work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setApplicationContext(context);

        return handler;
    }
}
```

Then you can successfully access

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(@environment.getProperty('role.rolename')")
public void method() {}
```