# Spring security + taglibs jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, jsp-tags

I have a public class with constants to contract the available ROLES of my application.
I want to do this to be able to "refactor" role names in a future.

At my JSP I have this, but it doesn't works:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('<%=Roles.ROLE_CAN_EXPORT%>')">
```

If I hard code the role name, it works:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_CAN_EXPORT')">
```

Comment: I changed to <sec:authorize ifAllGranted="<%=Roles.ROLE_CAN_EXPORT%>"> and worked.... but the question above continues!

Comment: Another way is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207248/spring-security-preaurhorize-hasrole-properties-injection/18207602#18207602)