# How to resolve properties from property file in PreAuthorize?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-el

In my `test.properties` file I have a key named `devmode`.
Doing `${devmode}` inside `@PreAuthorize` fails.

```
@PreAuthorize("${devmode}")
```

**How can I get the values of my properties inside a PreAuthorize?**

I am loading the properties file like this:
`<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/test.properties" />`

Using the value inside `<security:http use-expressions="true">` like this works:   `<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/dev/**" access="${devmode}" />`
This also works:
`@Value(${devmode}) String myVar;`
So I can't really see why it shouldn't work.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I had this before:

```
@PreAuthorize("#key == 'mysecretkey'")
```

and it worked. However, I want to not have that key in code, but inside my .properties file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207248/spring-security-preaurhorize-hasrole-properties-injection/18207602#18207602

Comment: @MaksymDemidas except that I'm not trying to use `hasRole()`

Comment: Sorry, it is true. Anyway you can try to use the same solution.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the devmode variable resolves to a role name, try this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('${devmode}')")
```

Comment: Tried changing a `("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` to `"hasRole('${test.key}')"` with ROLE_ADMIN as the test.key property. Doesn't work when using the test.key, works otherwise. No error message

Comment: try `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('${'test.key'}')")`. The Spring Expression Language supports nested single quotes within expressions.

Comment: @Ritesh that crashes with `Unexpected token.  Expected 'rparen())' but was 'identifier'` on pos12.

Comment: ok. As per [Literal expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-literal): _To put a single quote itself in a string use two single quote characters._ Maybe that can be tried.