# Grails 3 and Spring Security @Secured

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I know I can configure the secured annotation by specifying something like this on my controller:

```
@Secured('ROLE_ADMINISTRATORS')
class HomeController {
    ... methods and things
}
```

Now, how would I go about injecting a property from the YML configuration file? Say my current YML file reads as follows:

```
security:
    roles:
        admins: ROLE_ADMINISTRATORS
        viewers: ROLE_VIEWERS
        managers: ROLE_MANAGERS
```

If I change my @Secured annotation to read as this

```
@Secured('${security.roles.admins}')
```

the application complains with this error:

```
EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

I then try to use the @PreAuthorize annotation, [this post shows how it can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836387/can-spring-evaluate-all-characters-expressions-in-spel-expressions-as-they-are-i), as this:

```
@PreAuthorize('${security.roles.admins}')
```

But I get an error stating:

```
Attribute 'value' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize
```

Is it possible to inject properties into either one of these annotations, so that I can use it with Grails 3 and [Spring Security LDAP plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#secured-annotation)?