# @PreAuthorize hasRole value using Property Injection

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

We are trying to inject value to hasRole() as below

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(${role.rolename})")
public void method() {}
```

but it is not working

Also tried below solution

```
@RestController("appVariablesHolder")
public class AppVariablesHolder {

@Value("${role.rolename}") 
private String someRole;

public String getSomeRole() {
    return this.someRole;
}
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole(@appVariablesHolder.getSomeRole())")
public void method() {}
```

But getting the error

```
{"exception": { "name":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"Failed to evaluate 
 expression \u0027hasRole(@appVariablesHolder.getSomeRole())\u0027"
}
}
```

How can I inject @value as parameter in hasRole() method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747452/how-to-use-custom-expressions-in-spring-security-preauthorize-postauthorize-an

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207248/spring-security-preaurhorize-hasrole-properties-injection

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836387/can-spring-evaluate-all-characters-expressions-in-spel-expressions-as-they-are-i

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use custom expressions in Spring Security @PreAuthorize/@PostAuthorize annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747452/how-to-use-custom-expressions-in-spring-security-preauthorize-postauthorize-an)